# HTML/CSS to Animate Gif (or video) on Hover based on mouse position

Tags: html, css, animation, video, gif

I'm wondering if there's a way to animate a gif or video based on where my mouse is hovering in relation to the frame.

I think the best example of what I mean would be, if the gif is of someone turning around 360, I would want the person to be facing forward when the mouse in on the left of the frame, turned around when in the center of the frame, facing forward again when at the right of the frame (and all the in-betweens).

Effectively, using a mouse hover as a drag function for a video timeline

Let me know if you have any ideas or if you need more details.

If need be, I can upload some example gifs/videos to clarify my purpose.

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: Here's a click and drag version example of the same idea

https://kokokaka.com/demo/bluebell_ss10/site/#/collection/1

Comment: That is flash based. Many don't have flash installed. Provide another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotate()` on a class in CSS.

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/).